# Dataproc Pyspark job only running on one node

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

My problem is that my pyspark job is *not* running in parallel.

**Code and data format:**
My PySpark looks something like this (simplified, obviously):

```
class TheThing:
    def __init__(self, dInputData, lDataInstance):
        # ...
    def does_the_thing(self):
        """About 0.01 seconds calculation time per row"""
        # ...
        return lProcessedData

#contains input data pre-processed from other RDDs
#done like this because one RDD cannot work with others inside its transformation
#is about 20-40MB in size
#everything in here loads and processes from BigQuery in about 7 minutes
dInputData = {'dPreloadedData': dPreloadedData}

#rddData contains about 3M rows
#is about 200MB large in csv format
#rddCalculated is about the same size as rddData
rddCalculated = (
    rddData
        .map(
            lambda l, dInputData=dInputData: TheThing(dInputData, l).does_the_thing()
        )
)

llCalculated = rddCalculated.collect()
#save as csv, export to storage
```

**Running on Dataproc cluster:**
Cluster is created via the [Dataproc UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters).
Job is executed like this:
`gcloud --project <project> dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster <cluster_name> <script.py>`

I observed the job status via the UI, [started like this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces#step_2_-_connect_with_your_web_browser).  Browsing through it I noticed that only one (seemingly random) of my worker nodes was doing anything.  All others were completely idle.

Whole point of PySpark is to run this thing in parallel, and is obviously not the case.  I've run this data in all sorts of cluster configurations, the last one being massive, which is when I noticed it's singular-node use.  And hence why my jobs take too very long to complete, and time seems independent of cluster size.

All tests with smaller datasets pass without problems on my local machine and on the cluster.  I really just need to upscale.

**EDIT**
I changed
`llCalculated = rddCalculated.collect()`
`#... save to csv and export`
to
`rddCalculated.saveAsTextFile("gs://storage-bucket/results")`

and only one node is still doing the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you loaded `rddData` from GCS or HDFS, the default split size is likely either 64MB or 128MB, meaning your 200MB dataset only has 2-4 partitions. Spark does this because typical basic data-parallel tasks churn through data fast enough that 64MB-128MB means maybe tens of seconds of processing, so there's no benefit in splitting into smaller chunks of parallelism since startup overhead would then dominate.

In your case, it sounds like the per-MB processing time is much higher due to your joining against the other dataset and perhaps performing fairly heavyweight computation on each record. So you'll want a larger number of partitions, otherwise no matter how many nodes you have, Spark won't know to split into more than 2-4 units of work (which would also likely get packed onto a single machine if each machine has multiple cores).

So you simply need to call `repartition`:

```
rddCalculated = (
    rddData
        .repartition(200)
        .map(
            lambda l, dInputData=dInputData: TheThing(dInputData, l).does_the_thing()
        )
)
```

Or add the repartition to an earlier line:

```
rddData = rddData.repartition(200)
```

Or you may have better efficiency if you repartition at read time:

```
rddData = sc.textFile("gs://storage-bucket/your-input-data", minPartitions=200)
```

Comment: so the repartition number `repartition(x)`, should that be equivilant to the number of nodes or CPUs?

Comment: Seems `x` is max number of cores that each node has memory for.  Thanks @Dennis.  Hero of the week!

Comment: So, you can actually continue repartition more aggressively as long as each partition takes more than a few seconds to process; if you have more partitions than `number_of_nodes * cores_per_node`, this is actually an okay pattern, it just means your workers will chug through those partitions in more than 1 "wave". So standard practice is either have partitions equal to the total number of cores available (to have everything done in 1 wave), or to make it some multiple of total number of cores. More partitions also lets you scale up the workers mid-job if necessary.

Comment: Typical limits are just when each partition becomes too small that scheduler overhead makes it inefficient (so try to keep time-per-partition above 5 seconds or so), and also there are scaling inefficiencies once you get into to 10,000 - 100,000 partitions range.

Comment: Thanks a million!  How severe are data copy overheads when processing each new partition?  Ultimately what I want to know is if there is a big _speed per cost_ difference between doing it in one wave compared to multiple waves?

Comment: Hard to say exactly, I would ballpark it at between 50ms and 1 second of effective CPU-time overhead per partition (a few inter-node network calls, a few distributed-filesystem calls), but as long as your data is coming from a distributed source (like `sc.textFile`) the overhead occurs in parallel, so shouldn't impact your walltime significantly. Personally, as long as the data splits up nicely, I always run my jobs with multiple waves, usually between 3x and 10x my available cores. I keep it to one wave if I'm doing something really heavy like Runtime.exec("ffmpeg ...") in each partition.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I was doing sorting benchmarks, I could shave off 10-15% of the time by making it fit in one wave, but that only worked when the data was very well-balanced. If my data was skewed or the operations done on each row had high variance for reasons like network connectivity to some external source, the total runtime was much better when using multiple waves. This is because with multiple waves, tasks that finish quickly first will allow their worker to run more tasks while the slow ones are still working on their first task.